# I have a list, how can I split words in list to get each letter from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

'I have a list, how can I split words in list to get each letter from list'
z = ["for", "core", "end"]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the two for approach

```
z = ["for", "core", "end"]
letters = []
for word in z:
    for element in word:
        letters.append(element)

print(letters)
#['f', 'o', 'r', 'c', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'd']
```